# Installing tensorflow without success

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to use tensorflow, tried to install it, and I recieve this error message when I import it. I even uninstalled the version 3.9 of python and installed the 3.8, which is the version it was designed for, but the same problem happens. Do you know why ?

PS C:\Users\Elève\Desktop\Python\Sudoku> & "C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" c:/Users/Elève/Desktop/Python/Sudoku/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Elève/Desktop/Python/Sudoku/main.py", line 3, in 
import tensorflow
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the C++ redist libraries
[C++ Redist lib](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: I've tried to do this, but it still does'nt work, with the same error message. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: just to download anaconda individual edition, create an environment called TF, install TF and you are done.. takes 2 min